# Report Portal Test NG integration

Tags: testng, reportportal

Can anybody provide me with a direct link to integrate maven test NG json pretty datapush to report portal?  I Googled a lot and could not find any direct documents.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can find working examples in a separate repository:
https://github.com/reportportal/examples-java

Check out `example-testng-log4j` module for TestNG with Log4j2 integration / configuration example. And `example-testng-logback` for TestNG with Logback. The latter is also has more case-study examples.

Answer (score 0):

ReportPortal agent and detailed information regarding the integration can be found here:
https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-testNG